# In a read-heavy MySQL database, is it ever worth creating a two-column table that holds an item_id and an item_summary (of data from 5 other tables)?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In this case, I'm working on a project that involves a database of library book data.  I have several tables in this database:

---

Books (book_id, title, description, genre_id, language_id, purchase_date, chapters, words, book_review_count)

BookSearchData (book_id, Fulltext-searchable titles and descriptions)

Genres (genre_id to genre_name)

Language (language_id to language_name)

CheckoutData (book_id, last_checkout_date, checkout_user_id)

---

A bit of table-construction rationale: I made separate Books and CheckoutData tables because in my setup, I will be making frequent requests for the CheckoutData information and won't need anything other than the data included in the CheckoutData fields.  Hopefully this was the right way to go.

The most frequent data request, however, will be a book data summary, which currently involves JOINs between all of the tables.  A book result includes the following information:

- Title
- Description
- Genre Name
- Language Name
- Purchase Date
- Chapters
- Words
- Review Count
- Checked Out?  (Which is determined by whether or not the value of checkout_user_id equals 0 in the CheckoutData table row associated with the book)

My question: Do you think it would be helpful (performance-wise) if I created another table in this database that included a simple two-colum setup consisting of a book_id and a book_data_summary?

The book_id would be, as you'd imagine, some kind of integer.  The book_data_summary would be a field of type TEXT.

The problem as I see it...this introduces a lot of data redundancy.  It also means that every time that a book is checked out (Table: CheckoutData) or if a book review is added by a user (Table: Books), I'll also need to update the book_data_summary field.

Is this worth doing?

Thanks!

**Edit:**  I need to clarify something.  In this case, I'm doing somewhat of a high-speed library scenario (yes, that seems kind of silly, but it's somewhat of an experimental project).  The CheckoutData table is going to be receiving a lot of inserts - very frequently (we're talking...a few hundred per minute).  And Book results will be requested at around the same rate, with perhaps 10 or 20 book entries being requested each time.

So TONS of checkouts, as well as TONS of requests for book summaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (we're talking...a few hundred per
>   minute)

60 seconds per minute, about 10 inserts per second. That is not very much, a database can handle thousands of inserts per second.

If you have a query with a performance problem, start using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to see what is going on and why things are slow.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I've been greatly underestimating database performance, haha.  I was concerned about how introducing too many JOINS into the mix would affect performance and I was trying to pre-optimize...probably not as necessary as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like a two column setup, but a denormalized version of the main query (e.g. create a view with all 5 tables joined appropriately, and then insert from there into another table) would have real benefits.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves - I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  Would you mind elaborating on your example?

Comment: You would build a table that contains all the columns from the joined tables, updating it either at some interval or when the data changes. So basically you could then query that table directly and get the same results as if you'd done the joins.

Comment: Oh, so you mean one table instead of my five tables?  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  Now I see what you meant in your first comment.  The only thing is (and I neglected to emphasize this in my original post), the CheckoutData is going to be receiving a lot of inserts - very frequently (we're talking...a few hundred per minute).  And Book results will be requested at around the same rate, with perhaps 10 or 20 book entries being called each time.  So in a one table setup, there would be a high read and high write rate.  Does this change your suggestion at all?  Thanks!

Comment: Ah...I just looked up "views" in MySQL.  I wasn't actually familiar with the term, and so I took it as meaning a temporary table that was generated by some joins.  Now I see what you actually meant.

Comment: Yea, that changes things for sure. In this case I'd just wait and see if it's actually a performance issue at all.

Comment: Ah, sounds good.  Thanks for your thoughts on all of this.  I guess I'll see how things go.  I was just trying to pre-optimize, which probably isn't the best way to go in this particular case.